# Adding prefix as a variable in route::group in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.3

I got this error message when i am trying to add prefix as a variable in route group

**error message :**

```
UrlGenerationException in UrlGenerationException.php line 17:
Missing required parameters for [Route: client.login] [URI: login].
```

**web.php :**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{account}'], function()
{
    Route::GET('login', ['as' => 'client.login', 'uses' => 'Client\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm']);

}
```

**controller :**

```
public function showLoginForm()
{

    return view('client.auth.login', $this->data);
}
```

Comment: Try without {} like this 'Route::group(['prefix' => 'account'], function()'

Comment: How did you access the URL in the view ?

Answer (score 1):

Your controller function must accept as arguments the URL params defined in the routes.

In this case it should be

```
public function showLoginForm($account)
{
    return view('client.auth.login', $this->data);
}
```

But you probably want to do something with account

Comment: same error , i also tried to dd($account) to see if the controller even work, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments, how are you invoking the route?